# Merging contacts not working

Tags: duplicate-contacts, civixero

I am trying to merge 2 contacts (individuals). I search for the contact, select both contacts and select merge. Go through the options. A message saying: Contacts Merged, Name has been updated. Contact ID 1951 has been deleted.

The contacts are not merged and no contacts are deleted.

The log file in ConfigAndLog has this message:

[error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

```
[code] => -5
[message] => DB Error: already exists
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => UPDATE  civicrm_account_contact  SET contact_id = 1951 , accounts_contact_id = '2bd64d12-13b0-4188-a708-430aa0bb8f5b' , accounts_display_name = 'Neil T - 1501' , last_sync_date = 20191018151509 , accounts_modified_date = 20191018000000 , accounts_data = 'Array' , accounts_needs_update = 0 , connector_id = 0 , plugin = 'xero' , do_not_sync = 0   WHERE (  civicrm_account_contact.id = 2598 )   [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '1951-0-xero' for key 'contact_id_plugin']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => UPDATE  civicrm_account_contact  SET contact_id = 1951 , accounts_contact_id = '2bd64d12-13b0-4188-a708-430aa0bb8f5b' , accounts_display_name = 'Neil T - 1501' , last_sync_date = 20191018151509 , accounts_modified_date = 20191018000000 , accounts_data = 'Array' , accounts_needs_update = 0 , connector_id = 0 , plugin = 'xero' , do_not_sync = 0   WHERE (  civicrm_account_contact.id = 2598 )   [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '1951-0-xero' for key 'contact_id_plugin']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: already exists" code=-5 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="UPDATE  civicrm_account_contact  SET contact_id = 1951 , accounts_contact_id = '2bd64d12-13b0-4188-a708-430aa0bb8f5b' , accounts_display_name = 'Neil T - 1501' , last_sync_date = 20191018151509 , accounts_modified_date = 20191018000000 , accounts_data = 'Array' , accounts_needs_update = 0 , connector_id = 0 , plugin = 'xero' , do_not_sync = 0   WHERE (  civicrm_account_contact.id = 2598 )   [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '1951-0-xero' for key 'contact_id_plugin']"]
```

)

Using latest version of Drupal + Civi

Comment: Ben - you should be precise on versions rather than just saying latest so the question continues to be useful,

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with xero (I'm assuming it's an extension/plugin that you have enabled on your site)?

If you are using fuzion's extension, you might want to check if it's already logged as an issue or if there is a solution already

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I will submit a post on the github site.